# Using parfor with temporary variable

Tags: matlab, parfor

I want to calculate count of outside points which are not in the circle. But I got this problem. My circle is unit circle.My Error is this : The temporary variable outside will be cleared at the beginning of each iteration
of the parfor loop.

```
function [  ] = girkoson( N,n )
%UNTİTLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
hold on
outside = 0;
parfor i=0:N
    E=ones(N,n);
    karekok = sqrt(n);
    E = [E, eig(randn(n))/karekok];
    a=real(E);
    b= imag(E);
    plot(a,b,'.r');  
        if (a>= -1) | (a<=1) | (b>=-1) | (b<=1)
        outside = outside +1;
        fprintf('%f',outside);
        end
end

derece=0:0.01:2*pi; 
xp=1*cos(derece);
yp=1*sin(derece);
x=0;y=0;
plot(x+xp,y+yp,'-b');
hold off
end
```

Comment: What problem? You just dumped your code here. What is your question?

Comment: I have just edited

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to treat `outside` as a `parfor` [*reduction*](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/classification-of-variables-in-parfor-loops.html) variable. You cannot access the intermediate values of reduction variables during the loop - you can only perform the reductions. In other words, the line `fprintf('%f', outside)` is causing the problem, you must remove this for the `parfor` loop to work.

Also note that workers operating on the body of your `parfor` loop cannot display graphics to your desktop, so your `plot` calls will not show anything on-screen. (You can use `print` to emit graphics to a file if you wish).

Comment: I didnt use print because plot can display the circle and points.